# DynamoDB table design with audit log

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'd like to add audit log for my current dynamodb table.

Currently I have a single table 'deployments' which represents versions of deployed services.

The number of records here is rather small (<200) and does not change too much in time. I can quite quickly get all the items using 'scan' query in lambda which in the end is used by GUI to render website (so it's executed quite often by users). The schema for the table is PK - environment-name, SK - service-name, Attr Version.

I'd like to add here audit log so it would be quite easily get history of deployed versions but on the same time would be good to get all the current items with single query.

Do you recommend any approach here?

- I'm thinking about about having separate history table which would be updated by DynamoDB streams
- I'm thinking about including history in the same table as some aws docs recommend, but - correct my if I'm wrong I would not be able to easily get all the current items with single query then

Appreciate your feedback
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this but I think the simplest is to 
write 2 items to DDB every time you update:

1. PK - environment-name, SK - service-name, Attr Version.
2. PK - environment-name, SK - service-name, **current**.

Since sort keys can be conditional you could write a query like this:
*PK = environment-name, and SK contains("current")* 

But here you still need to know the environment name to make the request.
Unless we are talking many different PKs then, let's say there are at most 5 then just running 5 queries in parallel would work really well as DDB have very low latency.

If it's a hard requirement to get all items in one request then you could
do the same as above but also add a `status` column to the second item and write **current** in it. Then you could have a global secondary index and add the `status column as PK. But note that this will make the write request count 3 pr updates instead of 2 in the first suggestion, making it more costly. Also with this suggestion, you risk getting a hot partition.